# Auth0 + JWT + NodeJS + Express End-user authentication (Login)

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, auth0

Has been almost a year that I switch to Auth0 in order to manage my customer's access to the dashboard of my application. Nowadays I need to implement access for a RESTFULL API.

If I follow the instructions in order to secure the NodeJS app using JWT it works like a charm. The issue is that I am not properly sure on the implementation for the end user in order to get the token needed for access this API.

I thought of creating the **tokens** on the dashboard or just use a server side implementation for the login/authentication. I did the last using the access to my own database before and worker amazingly. **My issue is that I am not completely sure on how to do it for the end user using Auth0**.

**Anyone implemented a RESTfull API that has login using Auth0 before in order to get the JWT token ?** Would my great to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use a different approach.

There is an Auth0 endpoint that uses the user and password for the user in order to login with the service. This way I can get the id of the authenticated user and a JWT token that I can use to validate future requests.

https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#resource-owner-password

> This flow should only be used from highly trusted applications that cannot do redirects. If you can use redirect-based flows from your apps we recommend using the Authorization Code Grant instead.

```js
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: process.env.AUTH0_URL_OAUTH,
    headers: {
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
      grant_type: 'password',
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
      audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
      scope: process.env.AUTH0_SCOPE,
      client_id: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET
    },
    json: true
  };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      res.sendStatus(500); //We could not connect to the service
    } else {
      if (body.error) {
        console.log(body);
        res.status(400);
        res.send({
          error: body.error_description // There was an error with the user or password
        });
      } else {
        console.log(body);
        /**
         * Everything went well. We return the JWT
         */
        res.send({
          access_token: body.access_token,
          expires_in: body.expires_in,
          token_type: body.token_type
        });
      }
    };
```